# Can't connect to workbench on newly installed Linux and MySQL on Azure

Tags: linux, mysql, azure

I created a new `Ubuntu` Server v18 on `Microsoft Azure`.
I created an inbound rule to allow `port 3306`

I ran `updates and upgrades`

I did `sudo apt install mysql-server`

I checked to make sure it was running with:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

And now I'm trying to connect to it via `MySQL Workbench`
and can't connect to it when i click the `test connection` button

What else am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked if the firewall inside VM to allow port 3306?

Comment: @Rod If the answer is helpful or for more help, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

To expose MySQL to anything other than localhost you will have to have the following line

**For mysql version 5.6 and below**

uncommented in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and assigned to your computers IP address and not loopback

**For mysql version 5.7 and above**

uncommented in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and assigned to your computers IP address and not loopback

Replace xxx with your IP Address

```
bind-address        = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Or add a  `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` if you don't want to specify the IP.

Then stop and restart MySQL with the new my.cnf entry. Once running go to the terminal and enter the following command.

```
lsof -i -P | grep :3306
```

That should come back something like this with your actual IP in the xxx's

```
mysqld  1046  mysql  10u  IPv4  5203  0t0  TCP  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306 (LISTEN)
```

If the above statement returns correctly you will then be able to accept remote users. However for a remote user to connect with the correct priveleges you need to have that user created in both the localhost and '%' as in.

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
then,

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

and finally,

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
EXIT;
```

Then you can connect to your mysql.

Hope this will help you.